# Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec with multiple parameters

Tags: java, runtime

So I trying to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to execute a openview command from Java code. This exact command runs fine on command prompt on the server does the necessary updates, but fails to perform when executed through Java code. The issue is that it returns exit status code of success i,e "0" when invoked through Java, but doesn't performs the updates it is suppose to do (appears like it is not executing).

Here is the command :

```
opcmsg application='Tester Down 11' object='My Support' severity=minor msg_grp='MyGroup' msg_text='DEV: -m=New Details:Request Detail description'
```

Here is the code :

```
String[] command = { 
    "opcmsg", 
    "application=\'Tester Down 11\'", 
    "object=\'My Support\'", 
    "severity=minor", 
    "msg_grp=\'MyGroup\'", 
    "msg_text=\'DEV: -m=New Details:Request Detail description\'" 
}
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String errorDescription = null;

while ( (errorDescription = br.readLine()) != null)
    LOGGER.info(errorDescription);

    exitStatus = p.waitFor();
    LOGGER.info("exitStatus : " + exitStatus);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked :

```
String[] command = { "/bin/sh",
     "-c",
     "opcmsg application=\'Tester Down 11\' object=\'My Support\' severity=minor msg_grp=\'MyGroup\' msg_text=\'DEV: -m=New Details:Request Detail description\' "  }
```