# What is a stable way to perform command line operations with multiple parameters from Java?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, command-line

I have read several questions about how to execute an external program from Java, for example:

[Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913817/using-runtime-getruntime-exec-with-multiple-parameters/49951123#49951123)

[How to execute command with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

[Java: Running cmd commands (multiple commands with multiple arguments at once)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072849/java-running-cmd-commands-multiple-commands-with-multiple-arguments-at-once)

and probably a couple more, but none of the suggested solutions works for me.

Code:

```
public static void freezeAllChromeInstances() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] freezeAllChromeInstances = {"/usr/bin/killall", "-STOP "
            + "\'Google Chrome\'"
            + "chromedriver-mod"
            + "\'Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)\'"
            + "\'Google Chrome Helper\'"
            + "\'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)\'"};
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = run.exec(freezeAllChromeInstances);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    pr.waitFor();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Quite simple to understand: I want to pause everything Chrome. Running `/usr/bin/killall -STOP 'Google Chrome' chromedriver-mod 'Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)' 'Google Chrome Helper' 'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)'` from the command line works as expected but my code above has no effect at all.

I have tried with a single string, a string array as above, with or without escaping the apostrophes, combining `kill` and `-STOP` in one string and so on.

How are you supposed to do this? Would be good with a final, works for all, solution.

---

Update: forgot to mention - I have also tried

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/killall", "-STOP "
            + "\'Google Chrome\'"
            + "chromedriver-mod"
            + "\'Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)\'"
            + "\'Google Chrome Helper\'"
            + "\'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)\'");
    Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You concatenate the chrome process names to a single one without spaces by using '+' instead of ','. Changing this works for me (I added the last one because this is the name of the process in my Ubuntu):

```
String[] freezeAllChromeInstances = {"/usr/bin/killall", "-STOP", 
                                     "\'Google Chrome\'", 
                                     "\'chromedriver-mod\'",
                                     "\'Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)\'",
                                     "\'Google Chrome Helper\'",
                                     "\'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)\'",                           
                                     "/opt/google/chrome/chrome"};
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(freezeAllChromeInstances);
pr.waitFor();
```

Same goes for the ProcessBuilder version - you need to create a String[] there as well:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/usr/bin/killall", "-STOP", 
                                       "\'Google Chrome\'", 
                                       "\'chromedriver-mod\'",
                                       "\'Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)\'",
                                       "\'Google Chrome Helper\'",
                                       "\'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)\'",                           
                                       "/opt/google/chrome/chrome"});
Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, I think there is no need to sleep a second if you wait for the process to terminate anyways. And it may also help to print the `getErrorStream()` output as well.